# convert a fully quoted csv file to tsv format

Tags: bash, sed, ksh

I have a file like:

```
"a","b","c"...
```

And want to convert the comma to tab for the delimiter.

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/","/"\t"/g' < input_file > output_file
```

Yet, it looks the only effect is to change the comma to the literal character t:

```
"a"t"b"t"c"...
```

Anything wrong with my sed expression?

Comment: Your version of `sed` doesn't recognize `\t` as a literal tab.

Comment: @chepner, I am under bash. What shall I do then? Sed doesn't recognize `\t` as a tab? What's wrong with the sed? By the way, I am on AIX machine.

Comment: Also, you did not terminate your single quote.

Comment: Dunno. Worked fine for me... What is the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, What a joke! Sed on AIX can't even recognize the "--" option.

Comment: AIX machine:  just press the <Tab> key for a `\t`.  (you'll get the visual run of spaces to the next tab stop on your current line). In general AIX progs don't recognize any `--` option unless you install the GNU tools packages (Hard to get done in a typical AIX environment that is locked down). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks a lot for your help and detailed explanation, bro.

Comment: @shellter shouldn’t you need to press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> before the Tab? My shells otherwise interpret it as tab completion. – As for the original problem: this will also trash a field consisting solely of a comma. Unfortunately, CSV (any variant with quotes) isn’t really shell-safe. I invented [SSV](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=shellsnippets/shellsnippets.git;a=tree;f=mksh/ssv;h=fbe2c62aea46a2dadba980fc88fa87257c39b133;hb=HEAD) for this (currently using a C program to parse CSV into SSV, but could be done in shell as well). It eliminates quotes & makes newlines safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with non GNU versions of sed, if possible use space as delimier or paste tab instead of sed, or use `$(printf \t)`  instead of `\t`